# Tenses/Voices that show whether something is finite or not

Tags: grammar, tense, grammatical-voice

Are there any languages which have a tense or voice that shows whether something is finite.

For this example only I will indicate in the present tense that something is finitely true by adding an "-n" to the end of the verb.

> I am hungryn.
>
> I chose to say that being hungry was finitely true because, once I eat, I will no longer be hungry and the sentence no longer will be true.

In this next example, I will just add an "-r" to the end of the verb to indicate that what is being said by my clause as a whole will always be true and is therefore infinitely true.

> Gravity causes objects to becomer attracted to eachother.
>
> I chose the infinitely true conjugation for this because what I had said in the sentence will always be true- if there is the existance of gravity, that is the result.

Anyhow, I am wondering if other languages have something that funtions like this or is similar to this.

Comment: The closest thing that exists in (most) languages is the grammatical aspect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect - perfective vs imperfective.

Comment: @Lubos or for his -r example, the gnomic aspect.

Comment: Actually, modern English often (though not consistently) makes that distinction. For most verbs, (but not verbs of sensation or inner experience), the simple present is not used for what you call finite senses.

Comment: Many Australian languages have a 'habitual' aspect, which comes close to what you are asking. [Telic aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicity) may also be relevant.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut This is more to clarify, but is telic more of the continued *idea* of something being able to be in existance regardless of its physical existance and instead dependent upon its functionality in a general or habitiual sense?

Comment: I think its about whether or not an event is inherently bounded in time, or not. So while it may not be quite what you're after, I thought it could be a notion/term that would help you find a language with the features you seek.